# Potential Bug: pandas MultiIndex and 0-d sized values

Tags: python, pandas

It is python policy to ignore 0-d arrays. There is technically no difference between `0` and `array(0)`. For standard pandas, this is supported. However, not so much with `MultiIndex`. Consider

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(1234)
# params, initials
T = 100 # time
N = 80 # firms
TIndex = np.arange(0, T)
FIndex = np.arange(0, N)

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([TIndex, FIndex], names=['time', 'firm'])
df = pd.DataFrame(-999, columns=['A', 'w', 'l', 'a', 'x', 'X', 'd', 'profit'], index=index)
t, n = 0, 2
df.loc[(t,n), 'X'] = np.array(0)

pd.__version__
df.loc[(t,n), 'X']
```

This will give me a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2883, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-180-766f1cc7a0e5>", line 1, in <module>
    df.loc[(t,n), 'X'] = np.array(0)
  File "C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 119, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "C:\Users\sdaro\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 342, in _setitem_with_indexer
    if is_list_like(value) and lplane_indexer != len(value):
TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

**Update**

To address the first comment; What I mean by "technically no difference" is that "in most cases", applications designed to take in values are supposed to also take in singletons. `pandas` supports this in general, as demonstrated by

```
>>> test = pd.DataFrame(index = array([0, 1, 2]), columns=['A'])
>>> test.ix[0, 'A'] = 1
>>> test.ix[1, 'A'] = array(1)
>>> test
Out[190]: 
     A
0    1
1    1
2  NaN
```

It is just in this special case that it does not work, which is why I suggest this is not intended behavior.

Comment: "There is technically no difference between `0` and `array(0)`." - there is. They behave much alike, but it would be dangerous to treat them as the same. For example, the array is mutable: `x = numpy.array(0); x[...] = 1; print x` will print `array(1)`.

Comment: we do accept this in the case of a non-multi-index, so will call this a bug; see here. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7218 (in general this is not good practice though; simply assign a scalar)

Comment: Yes, updated regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we do accept this in the case of a non-multi-index, so will call this a bug

issue is here: http://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7218

fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/7219